# Clarification - Why do we need to wrap nested async/awaits in another async/await?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I've been looking more into `async/await` and trying to understand exactly when to use/not use it. One thing that still puzzles me is whether you make an outer function `async` when it is only calling a nested `async` function.

I understand that `async/await` wraps a return value in a Promise. But does the outer function need to do this wrapping as well, even when it is only responsible for executing the inner `async` function, and not actually using a return value (thus not needing to wait for one)?

Let's say an example is an app that is posting messages to a server.

```
const someFunction = (userId) => {
   const message = 'Some message'
   try {
      asyncFunc(userId, message)
   } catch (e) {
      console.error(e)
   }
}
```

The inner `async` function is responsible for the actual posting and this will be written with `async/await`.

If `someFunction` needs to also return a Promise and therefore be made into an `async` function, then does this mean any outer function that also calls `someFunction` will also need to be wrapped? Does every outer function calling an `async` function have to be wrapped up to the outer most layer?

Comment: You can call an `async` function from a non-`async` context, but you have to deal with the returned Promise yourself (via `.then()` etc). You can only use `await` inside an `async` function.

Comment: The function where you end up calling the async function doesn't need to be async, nor would it typically be. The async function returns a promise. Therefor, you need to call `asyncFunc(userId, message).then()` in order to consume the promise.

Comment: Thank you both @Pointy @silencedogood - as a follow up, I don't necessarily need to consume the promise, just need to make the post with the API. If there are race conditions I need to consider, such as a limit to the amount of messages that can be sent (and this can be potentially triggered by multiple people at once), would it then be appropriate to make the caller function `async`?

Comment: If you want the `try`/`catch` to handle errors from the `asyncFunc()` call, then you *are* using the result and have to wait for it.

Comment: This clarifies some things for me @Bergi thank you 